# how add list, string and int into dapper select query

Tags: .net, .net-core, orm, dapper

At the input of the method, I have a model that consists of 
{
   "Id": [
     "string"
   ],
   "Status": "string",
   "systemStatus": "string"
}
I checked the request in ssms and it works, but in debugging this method I see different result.
dapper takes the first id and return 1 users, but in the sql studio returns 6 people

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<User>> FindUser(Users model)
        {
            DynamicParameters parameters = new DynamicParameters();
            parameters.Add("@Id", model.Id);
            parameters.Add("@Status", model.Status);
            parameters.Add("@systemStatus", model.SystemStatus);

            IEnumerable<User> items = null;

            var sql = @"SELECT statusesid FROM userstatuses WHERE [id] IN (@Id) 
                                          AND [status] in (@Status) and [systemStatus] in (@systemStatus)";
            try
            {
                using (var db = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                {
                    if (db.State != ConnectionState.Open)
                        await db.OpenAsync();

                    items = await db.QueryAsync<User>(sql, parameters);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                _logger.Error(e);
            }
            return items;
        }
```

i try use string.Join(",", model.Id) but same result( how correctly add list, string and int into dapper select query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you have list in sql you need write only "SELECT * FROM TableA WHERE id IN **@ids**" without brackets and dapper will put them down independently

Answer (score 0):

Dapper interpret sql "in" in a different way. Have a look to below conversion for in sql operator and try accommodate your change accordingly:

Sql Query :

```
SELECT * FROM TableA WHERE id IN (commaSeparatedlistOfIDs)
```

Dapper conversion of above query :

```
string sql = "SELECT * FROM TableA WHERE id IN @ids"
var results = conn.Query(sql, new { ids = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }});
```